# insert into department_new select a.*,null from departments a;" what does select a.* means

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert data from one table to another in mysql, so would like to understand the below query

```
insert into department_new select a.*,null from departments a;
```

what does `select a.*` means and how does it insert the values correctly into a new table,

kindly help

Comment: Your query is undesirable because it leaves the columns being selected up to possible change.  If the order of columns changes for some reason, your insert query could break or if running be logically wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a` is an alias for table `departments`

and `a.*` means all column so it is the same as `departments.*`

So the complete Statement

```
insert into department_new select a.*,null from departments a;
```

means, that all values from table departments should be stored into the table `department_new` plus a new column where null should be inserted.

It only works fine, if the order in both tables are equals. In this form there is the risk, that you copy the values to a wrong column.

Comment: Thank you, Jens, you answered my query

Answer (score 0):

It means select all columns from table a which is the departments table.

Comment: what i would like to know is ,in this query we have select a.* , null from debartments a; what does " a.* " and "a" at the end symbolizes.